# how to parse json data recieved as a string

Tags: android, json

```
[
    {"CityName":"Jaipur","CityId":1},
    {"CityName":"Jodhpur","CityId":2},
    {"CityName":"Ajmer","CityId":3},
    {"CityName":"Bikaner","CityId":4}

]
```

I want to get all the citynames and their id but i don't know how to do that. As I new to android any answer will be a great help for me..Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look at gson: https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: what u try and what u search for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

Your getting response as `JSONArray` like below

**JSON**

```
[                                  //JSONArray  array
    {                              //JSONObject jObj
        "CityName": "Jaipur",      //optString cityName
        "CityId": 1                //optInt CityId
    },
    {
        "CityName": "Jodhpur",
        "CityId": 2
    },
    {
        "CityName": "Ajmer",
        "CityId": 3
    },
    {
        "CityName": "Bikaner",
        "CityId": 4
    }
]
```

**Code**

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response);
for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
  JSONObject jObj = array.optJSONObject(i);
  String cityName = jObj.optString("CityName");
  int CityId = jObj.optInt("CityId");
  Log.v("cityName :",""+cityName);
  Log.v("CityId :",""+CityId);
}
```

Comment: @pks Gald it helped. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
JSONArray jarray   =new JSONArray(response);
 String[] cityName = new String[jarray.length()]  
JSONObject jObject=null;
for(int j=0;j<jarray.length();j++){
  jObject=jarray.getJSONObject(j);
  cityName[j]=jObject.getString("CityName");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
ArrayList<String> cityname=new ArrayList<String>();

   JSONArray jsonarr=new JSONArray(string);
    for(i=0;i<jsonarr.length();i++){

    cityname.add(jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("CityName"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON classes for parsing e.g

```
JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(Your_Sring_data);
String  CityName= mainObject .getJSONObject("CityName");
String CityId= mainObject .getJSONObject("CityId");
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray= jsonResponse.getJSONArray("your_json_array_name");
for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject= jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String name = jsonObject.getString("CityName");
   String id = jsonObject.getString("CityId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use json-path library it will simplifies the JSON parsing.

You can download json-path lib from [here](https://code.google.com/p/json-path/)

Then add this library to your project /libs/ folder.

Then import the project name like this

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
```

Then parse your JSON data like this

```
JSONArray jsonData= new JSONArray(JsonPath.read(jsonStringData,"$..CityId[*]").toString());
```